# Build OpenSSL RSA from components

Tags: c, openssl, openssh, libcrypto

I've looked just about everywhere for the answer to this, but I think what I really need is for someone with relevant experience with OpenSSL to point me in the right direction.

In Python there's a library, PyCryptodome, which has pure Python implementations of several cryptography algorithms, including RSA. They have a function as a part of the RSA module called [`construct`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.construct) which builds an RSA key out of its various components (`n`, `e`, `d`, `p`, and `q`). I haven't been able to find a similar function in OpenSSL though, likely just because I don't know where to look in their documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL allows you to provide these values by creating your own RSA struct (via `RSA_new()`) and then populating it via `RSA_set0_key`, `RSA_set0_factors`, and `RSA_set0_crt_params`.

Note that you can completely define an RSA public/private key with just `n, e, d`, but there are several additional values traditionally provided (e.g. `p` and `q` are the primes that form the modulus while `iqmp`, `dmp1` and `dmq1` are CRT coefficients).

OpenSSL requires you to provide these as `BN *` instances and you **must not free the BN instances** after assigning them via the `set0` functions. When you see a function with that naming scheme in OpenSSL it means you're setting a value, but it does not increment the reference count so if you free the `BN *` yourself it will become an invalid pointer in the struct.

You can see exactly how this works in the [pyca/cryptography source](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py#L416-L448), but I strongly recommend against doing this yourself unless you're very comfortable with OpenSSL and its foibles.